# How do I make fonts work in an EPUB?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, epub

I'm helping my friend with a "remixed novel" for one of her classes. Basically, we have to add styles and stuff to a classic text and bundle it as an epub so it can be read with an eReader. I think everything is saved in folders correctly and it seems to be coded right. It works on my Tumblr when I put the code into their console, but when I try to open the XHTML directly with Firefox it doesn't display my fonts or style, as if it's not linking to the stylesheet properly. Here are screencaps of what it looks like and what it should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pszI.jpg

The folder with all my html and stuff in it is available here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95719489/Sherlock%20Holmes.zip

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: A question should contain sufficiently code that makes it possible to reconstruct the problem, instead of just referring to external resources.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS file has some errors. Use the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to find them. For example, after the `@font-face` rules, you have a rule without any selector.

Second, since the XHTML file is processed as genuine XHTML (XML), tag names are case-sensitive: `p` and `P` are different tag names, and therefore the CSS code should use `p` (the XHTML tag name), not `P`.

Note that epub readers should generally not be expected to support `@font-face`. They may, or they may not. Also note that `text-align:justify` easily causes catastrophic results when the viewport is narrow (e.g., in typical pocket-size devices).